# Подключение php-расширения в Azure

Tags: php, windows, azure-websites

Выполнил все рекомендации в [этой](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/silverlining/using-custom-php-extensions-in-windows-azure-web-sites) статье, но модуль не подключается.
Некоторая инфа с phpinfo():

> PHP Version 5.5.26 Build Date     Jun 10 2015 13:59:20 Compiler   MSVC11
> (Visual C++ 2012) Architecture    x86  PHP Extension Build
> API20121212,NTS,VC11
>
> PHP_EXTENSIONS    bin\php_mongo-1.6.8-5.5-vc11-nts.dll
> APPSETTING_PHP_EXTENSIONS     bin\php_mongo-1.6.8-5.5-vc11-nts.dll

Скрины настроек в азуре
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohdU9.png

Comment: На сервере dll тоже загружены http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW5wV.png